# Convert ordered levels to numeric in pandas

Tags: pandas

I was wondering is there any function in pandas that allows me to do this.

I have a column with levels [low, medium, high].

I would like to translate them to [1,2,3] to perform linear regression. However, what i am currently doing is `df[df['interest_level'] == 'low'] = 1`. is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [pd.factorize()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) method:

```
df['interest_level'] = pd.factorize(df['interest_level'])[0]
```

you can also categorize your new numerical values (this might save a lot of memory):

Sample DataFrame:

```
In [34]: df = pd.DataFrame({'interest_level':np.random.choice(['medium','high','low'], 10)})

In [35]: df
Out[35]:
  interest_level
0           high
1            low
2         medium
3           high
4            low
5           high
6           high
7            low
8            low
9         medium
```

Solution:

```
In [36]: df['interest_level'], cats = pd.factorize(df['interest_level'])

In [37]: df['interest_level'] = pd.Categorical(df['interest_level'], categories=np.arange(len(cats)))

In [38]: df
Out[38]:
  interest_level
0              0
1              1
2              2
3              0
4              1
5              0
6              0
7              1
8              1
9              2

In [39]: cats      # this can be used for the backtracing ...
Out[39]: Index(['high', 'low', 'medium'], dtype='object')

In [40]: df.memory_usage()
Out[40]:
Index             80
interest_level    34   # <---- NOTE: only 34 bytes used for 10 integers
dtype: int64

In [41]: df.dtypes
Out[41]:
interest_level    category
dtype: object
```

Comment: I think there is problem predict you need `high` to `3`, low to `1`, because it depends of order in columns. What is first, it is convert to 0, then 1 and last to 2.

Comment: @jezrael, AFIK the values don't play a big role - the main problem is that regression/classification methods often don't accept non-numerical dtypes...

Comment: yes, it depends of OP. If is only necessary convert to numeric and mapping is not necessary, then is possible use your solution. But if order of values is changed, mapping will be different. So is impossible predict it.

Comment: @jezrael, OK, i've added another solution, which preserves also the categories...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
d = {'low':1,'medium':2,'high':3}

df['interest_level'] = df['interest_level'].map(d)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'interest_level':['medium','high','low', 'low', 'medium']})
print (df)
  interest_level
0         medium
1           high
2            low
3            low
4         medium

d = {'low':1,'medium':2,'high':3}
df['interest_level'] = df['interest_level'].map(d)
print (df)
   interest_level
0               2
1               3
2               1
3               1
4               2
```

Another solution is cast to `Categorical` and then use [`cat.codes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cat.codes.html):

```
categories = ['low','medium','high']
df['interest_level'] = df['interest_level'].astype('category',
                                                    categories=categories,
                                                    ordered=True).cat.codes + 1
print (df)
   interest_level
0               2
1               3
2               1
3               1
4               2
```